# Printing problems on a member of my TS farm

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, terminal-server, print-server

I have 2 , Server 2008R2 boxes as members of a Terminal Server farm.  I can use the printui.dll command "Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\" to successfully add printers globally to one of the machines.  (The printers reside on our print server).  The second machine I cannot remove or add any additional printers.  I used to be able to until after I deleted a few of the "Inactive TS ports" when trying to diagnose an issue with my HP Universal Print driver.

Even manually adding the printer through the print wizard fails.

I would like to add the printer for each user on the terminal server without resorting to a Group Policy implementation for printing. (which i suspect on this box would fail as well since I cannot manually add the printer).

Comment: Looks like I am going to clone the VM that works and rename make a new member of the farm.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up rebuilding the servers to resolve this issue.